# Add html to a list of values pulled from checked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="data_patient-name" value="Patient Name" class="checkbox">
        <label for="data_patient-name">Patient Name</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="data_wait-time" value="Wait Time" class="checkbox">
        <label for="data_wait-time">Wait Time</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="data_patient-satisfaction" value="Patient Satisfaction" class="checkbox">
        <label for="data_patient-satisfaction">Patient Satisfaction</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$(".checkbox").on("change", function(){
    var reportFields = [];
    $('.checkbox:checked').each(function(){        
        var fieldValues = $(this).next().text();
        reportFields.push(fieldValues);
    });
    $("ul.report-fields").html(reportFields.join(", "));
});
```

So this gives me a comma delimited list of values from checked checkboxes, awesome! However, I need to include some more information with that list of values. Namely, each value needs to be a list item that has a class name corresponding to the id of the checkbox. So in the end, I need to get a list that looks like this:

```
<ul class="report-fields">
    <li class="data_patient-name">Patient Name<sup><a href="#" class="remove" title="Remove">x</a></sup></li>
    <li class="data_wait-time">Wait Time<sup><a href="#" class="remove" title="Remove">x</a></sup></li>
    <li class="data_patient-satisfaction">Patient Satisfaction<sup><a href="#" class="remove" title="Remove">x</a></sup></li>
</ul>
```

So I've been playing around with the line in my JS:

```
$(".buildReportBox .report-fields ul").html(reportFields.join(", "));
```

but I'm having a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(".checkbox").on("change", function () {
    var reportFields = $('.checkbox:checked').map(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        return '<li class="' + this.id + '">' + $this.next().text() + '<sup><a href="#" class="remove" title="Remove">x</a></sup></li>'
    }).get();
    $("ul.report-fields").html(reportFields.join(''));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tGVsw/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function to do so:

```
$("ul.report-fields").html(reportFields.join(" ")).each(function(){
    $(this).wrap('<a class="yourclass" href="#path" />');
});
```